# How to overwrite self after reading yaml?

Tags: python, serialization, yaml

I have two classes that are inherited from the parent.

```
+------------+
|   Parent   |
|------------|
|attribute   |
+------------|
+------------+
      ^    ^
      |    +----------------+
      |                     |
+-----+------+        +-----+------+
|  SonSelf   |        | SonFromYaml|
|------------|        |------------|
|attribute   |        |            |
+------------|        +------------|
+------------+        +------------+
```

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute = None
```

The first class fills in its attributes (calculates them) and writes itself to the yaml file.

```
class SonSelf(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.attribute = 'not blank'
        with open('file.yml', 'w') as f:
            yaml.dump(self, f)
```

The second class reads these attributes from yaml.

```
class SonFromYaml(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        with open('file.yml', 'r') as f:
            ret = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.Loader)
        self = ret
```

But for some reason the created object turns out to be empty.

```
>>> son_self = SonSelf()
>>> son_from_yaml = SonFromYaml()

>>> print("son_self.attribute: ", son_self.attribute)
>>> print("son_from_yaml.attribute: ", son_from_yaml.attribute)
son_self.attribute:  not blank
son_from_yaml.attribute:  None
```

The `ret` object itself is identical to the `son_self` object. I can see this in debug.

[image]

Is it possible to do so:

```
self = ret
```

Or it is necessary to forcibly copy each field from the object obtained when reading the yaml?

```
class SonFromYaml(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        with open('file.yml', 'r') as f:
            ret = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.Loader)
        self.attribute = ret.attribute
```

Comment: ``self`` is just a local variable *referring to* the object. It is not the object itself.

Comment: Note that ``pyyaml`` ships with various means to load/store an actual Python object. That means that that ``pyyaml`` will create the instance, though; an instance cannot load itself after being created, since it already exists by then – it can only *modify* itself to match the loaded data.

Comment: Does this mean that this cannot be done in principle? That is, you need to copy the attributes?

Comment: Yes, if you want the instance to load itself. See the second-top answer in the duplicate on how to do that efficiently.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. If you were to frame this with an answer, I marked it with a solution.